# Rotation in the 3D space

Tags: calculus, geometry, differential-geometry, analytic-geometry

I have a rotation as a right-handed coordinate system and a right-handed rotation through an angle $\gamma$ around $z$-axis, an angle $\beta$ around $y$-axis  and an angle $\alpha$ around $x$-axis. I am wondering if this rotation can be rewritten as a rotation with angles $\theta_1$ in $yz$-axis (around $x$-axis) and $\theta_2$  in $xy$-plane (around z-axis)?

It seems yes, as I checked by several example. f it is true then, how I can prove it?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by a rotation with angle $\theta$ in $yz$-axis?

Comment: What id a rotation "in $xy$-plane"? Is it a rotation around the $z$ axis, or is it something else?

Comment: This question might be clearer if you included a few of the examples you worked out. But mainly if you showed what rotations you actually have allowed yourself to use. One rotation is sufficient if you can use any axis you want. Two is sufficient if you can choose any two axes from a predetermined plane (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1021727/is-it-true-that-a-arbitrary-3d-rotation-can-be-composed-with-two-rotations-const). If the axes are fixed, you need three rotations, two of which could be around the same axis.

Comment: sorry for answering the comments too late! I corrected the question

Answer (score 0):

To prove you can use the linear transformations, basically write the rotation matrices for any angle then it will be easy to show the equality. For more general proof you can simply analyse the linear dependence relation for your rotation matrices.

Comment: This may work when there is actually an equivalent set of rotations. In this case, based on the restrictions on the $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ rotations, this could not work generally. The question tries to represent a rotation using just two rotations around fixed axes, and this is not capable of reproducing all the rotations that a full set of Euler/Tait-Bryan rotations can provide.